# jquery 1.4.4 breaking Google map on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

im using a theme with a search/mapping function, all works great but since adding a button that calls some JS, the Google map doesn't load.

this is the code that breaks the map function

```
    <!-- Start Bookatable Code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.livebookings.com/lbui/plugins/direct/lbui.direct.min.js"></script>
    <a id="target" href="#">Book Now</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $("#target").lbuiDirect(
    {
    connectionid  :  "UK-TRENCHERMANSGUIDE:47231",
    style  :  {
    baseColor  :  "ee008c"
    },
    restaurantid  :  "101062",
    modalWindow  :  {
    enabled  :  true}
    });
    });
    </script>
    <!-- End Bookatable Code -->
```

How the pages should look http://insidersguide.segmant.co.uk/item/jamie-olivers-fifteen-cornwall/

This is what the page looks like when the 'BOOK NOW' button is on the page http://insidersguide.segmant.co.uk/item/orange-juice-bar/

This is driving me a little crazy, please help!!

Comment: Open up the console in your browser... it seems to be failing at three points.

Comment: You have not included the jQuery `autocomplete` plugin before you use it. Fix those errors first before blaming some other scripts.

Comment: @feeela: please pay more attention if you're going to edit tags, and actually spell them correctly. The tag editing system even autocompletes for you... How do you misspell autocomplete?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you loading a very old - 1.4.4 - jQuery library in the footer with the link in your code above? As well as the most recent jQuery library in the header? They are conflicting.

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what javascript is loading on your site and the errors.

Comment: Hi songdogtech, that code is generated for me by that Booking company, i can change it to load any version but it still causes the map not to load